# redirect user to another html page if the condition is true

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

First of all, I just want to say that I'm not good with html, all i know about html is from what i learn online by myself.

So.. I have a project and part of it is making a website. I already made the website but i have a problem..

My problem is I don't want to let the user access the setting, I want the admin to only access the setting, I did that by putting a password in setting page.. so if the user clicks on the setting icon, it will ask for a password, if its correct then the user can go to setting page

I have 3 pages (index.html which is my home page),(manager.html where my setting code is in) and (index4 where this code is in)
in index.html there a code which let the user go to index4.html page
and in index4.html page is this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

    <script>
        var pass;
        pass = prompt("please enter the password to access");
        if (pass == "11111"){
            <a href="manager.html">This is the link.</a>        
        } else {
            document.write("The password you've is enter is incorrect");
        }
</script>

<body>  

</html>
```

From what I learn online, href="link" code can redirect to another page.. but it seems I can't use it if it's in 'if statement'.
when I did inspect element,I got this error "Unexpected token '<'"

Can someone please tell me how to correct my mistake.

Comment: you can't use HTML in a javascript block .... `location` is what you need to check out

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use as bellow. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/1662751)

**For example:**

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting `document.location.href` - more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location)

```js
var pass;
pass = prompt("please enter the password to access");
if (pass == "11111") {
  document.location.href = "manager.html";
} else {
  document.write("The password you've is enter is incorrect");
}
```